# Hibernate : Insert column value from app instead of database

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I have a column in my Database, called `updateddate`, which should get inserted with sysdate through application.
If my application code encounters some exception, even then I want this column value to be inserted with sysdate through database. 
So, through SQL script, I have given this column default to sysdate.

Below is my hibernate hbm xml file,

```
<property name="updatedDate" type="timestamp">
    <column name="UPDATED_DATE" ></column>
</property>
```

However, the column is not getting inserted through my application when there are no exceptions. It is getting updated through DB.
I am saying this by looking at the date format.

How to make the column to be inserted through application and only when it encounters exception it should get inserted through DB?
I tried `insert=true`. But didn't help.

Comment: _"I am saying this by looking at the date format."_ Could you elaborate more on this please?

Comment: Date format in application code is dd-mm-yyyy without timestamp. Whereas date format inserted through DB is with timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure why you want to do this, but your application should set `updatedDate` to the current system date/time. The database default will only be applied if your application inserts a record with `updatedDate = null`.